# The list not updated after notifyDataSetChanged() in onActivityResult

Tags: notifydatasetchanged

I have some Activities. One of them must show listview using simpleCursorAdapter. In onItemClick() is method startActivityForResult() for other Activity (changes data in db). In method onActivityResult() I have notifyDataSetChanged(), but listview not updated. 
P.S. If I write notifyDataSetChanged() in onResume(), all are working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it may seem `notifyDataSetChanged()` won't work for you - this may be because your adapter loses reference to your list.

When you first initialize the `Adapter` it takes a reference of your `arrayList` and passes it to its superclass. But if you reinitialize your existing `arrayList` it losses the reference, and hence, the communication channel with `Adapter`.

When creating and adding a new list to the `Adapter`. Always follow these guidelines:

1. Initialize the `arrayList` while declaring it globally.
2. Add the List to the adapter directly with out checking for null and empty
   values . Set the adapter to the list directly (don't check for any
   condition). Adapter guarantees you that wherever you make
   changes to the data of the `arrayList` it will take care of it, but never loose the
   reference.
3. Always modify the data in the arrayList itself (if your data is completely new
   than you can call `adapter.clear()` and `arrayList.clear()` before
   actually adding data to the list) but don't set the adapter i.e If
   the new data is populated in the `arrayList` than just
   `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Stay true to the Documentation.